# Convert Map<String, String[]> to Map<String, Object[]> in java

Tags: java

Is there any method to convert the map obtained from servletRequest.getParameterMap() which returns a `Map<String, String[]>` to `Map<String, Object[]>` in a simple way other than a for loop?

I have a method getSomething() which is declared as

```
public Response getSomething(final Map<String, Object[])
```

I have to call this method with `servletRequest.getParameterMap()` as input.

Comment: Your question looks like [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you add more info about why you need this change?

Comment: Also what do you mean by *convert*? Can we assume that you want to get new independent map which will be copy of original one (since otherwise you could try adding `Integers` to array of Objects which really will be still array for Strings).

Comment: Just in case you don't know it: to add more informations to your question use [edit] option.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure.

```
Map<String, Object[]> objectMap = 
    Collections.unmodifiableMap(servletRequest.getParameterMap());
```

This is correct, type-safe, and doesn't risk problems with accidentally putting wrongly typed values into the map.

Comment: I also doesn't prevent us from trying to place non-string value to `String[]` array via `Object[]` reference (although this behaviour will be stopped at runtime).

Answer (score 0):

This way uses Java raw types.

```
Map<String, String[]> map1 = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, Object[]> map2 = (Map)map1;
```

This is a working solution although, as Pshemo pointed out, [java raw types shouldn't be used](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2770321/1631176).

Comment: Mandatory link: [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)